# MySQL - Upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, percona, percona-server

I have MySQL community version 5.5.50 running in linux having 4-5 databases on it.

Requirement is to upgrade to Percona Server 5.6.31-77.0.

What are the pre-requisites that I need to check before upgrading? Are there any common errors that i'm likely to face?

I'm simply planning to backup the databases. Remove the MySQL binaries. Install the new Percona Server and restore the databases.

Answer (score 1):

Backing up the database is a best practice right before upgrading to any version. You can use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html), [Xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html), [mydumper](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/11/12/logical-mysql-backup-tool-mydumper-0-9-1-now-available/) .

Replacing MySQL community packages with [Percona Server](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server) packages should do the job just make sure to execute [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html) after starting up PS 5.6 the first time.

> Percona Server is a free, fully compatible, enhanced, open source drop-in replacement for MySQL®

Always check the error log after the upgrade.

Comment: thanks can you also clarify what is the release frequency and why there are multiple versions of 5.6 in this page https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.6/LATEST/ ? They keep releasing new version or how is it like?

Comment: there are different versions depending on the SSL version installed on your system. `In Percona Server 5.6.24-72.2 and newer, the single binary tarball was replaced with multiple tarballs depending on the OpenSSL library available in the distribution`

Comment: oops sounds complicated, I use RHEL 6.4. So is it like I will have to carefully choose the right version?

Comment: Follow yum installation instructions instead of using generic tarballs? https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/installation/yum_repo.html

Comment: yum is not possible in my setup since I cannot connect to the internet to the download them.. I was in the assumption that Percona release new version which is a bug fix release.. I had the latest one downloaded and was thinking to proceed with that - it won't work right?

Comment: fwiw, just run `openssl version` and you'd know which one you'll need to download. try this one first- https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.6/Percona-Server-5.6.31-77.0/binary/tarball/Percona-Server-5.6.31-rel77.0-Linux.x86_64.ssl101.tar.gz, try to use that on an empty datadir, mysqld won't start if it's not compatible with your openssl version (afaik)

Comment: can you please confirm if I move from current version to your version, would there be any chance that the application running on it would have problems/issues because of this? I mean compatibility of application with this version. I checked the ssl version that is ok with my OS.. just that application's compatibility

Comment: what application are you running? in any case, I don't see any problems. if you use mysql drivers then upgrading them would be good too.